# Android JellyBean DatePicker Issue

Tags: android

I use a DatePicker within my Android Activity. I only have the need to display the year to the user. I use

```
private void findAndHideField(DatePicker datepicker, String name) {
        try {
            Field field = DatePicker.class.getDeclaredField(name);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            View fieldInstance = (View) field.get(datepicker);
            fieldInstance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and then

```
        findAndHideField(startDatePicker, "mDayPicker");
        findAndHideField(startDatePicker, "mMonthPicker");
        findAndHideField(startDatePicker, "mDaySpinner");
        findAndHideField(startDatePicker, "mMonthSpinner");
```

The code works fine on 2.3.x but on 4.1.x phone this just displays a full calender. What can i do to make only the year dial visible ?

Comment: Why not just use a `NumberPicker`? Here is a backport that should work going back to Android 2.1: https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker

Comment: No, i want it styled like the number picker, plus am not a big fan of including libraries. My project already has two external libraries and i think thats it. I seems such a trivial thing this, but i have been searching alot and cannot find anything.

Comment: "No, i want it styled like the number picker" -- one would think that `NumberPicker` would be "styled like the number picker". "plus am not a big fan of including libraries" -- it is a good thing that you do not work for me, as you would be out of a job. I would fire *anyone* who proposed script-kiddie hacking into private fields just because they do not want to add an open source library to their project. As you are discovering, your preferred technique breaks on various devices and OS versions.

Comment: ndroid:calendarViewShown="false". This does work.

Comment: @CommonsWare - You are very right. I agree.

Answer (score 2):

add these lines in your XML

```
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

to your **DatePicker**